# For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove $3n+3\leq4n+2.$

Tags: inequality

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove:
$3n+3\leq4n+2.$

I try as follows.

For all $n=1, 2, \ldots$ consider that
$$3n\leq4n\iff 3n+3\leq4n+3\iff 3n+3\leq^? 4n+2.$$
I write '${\leq}^?$' because I'm not sure if $3n+3\leq4n+3$ then $3n+3\leq 4n+2$ since $3>2$.

This is a simple inequality but I confused to prove it.
Anyone can help me to prove this inequality?

Comment: The inequality is not true, consider the case $n=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, '$<$' should be '$\leq$'

Comment: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $1 \leq n$. Maybe you can add something to both sides of this inequality.

Comment: One way to show $a \leq b$ is to show $b-a \geq 0$. Can you prove that?

Comment: I mean, can you prove the right hand side - left hand side of your inequality is non-negative?

Comment: @Lewis MacRae, I have tried to answer my question based on your hint.

Comment: @ArB Yes, I have tried to answer my question based on your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ Lewis MacRae comment's, I try as follows.

Consider that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
1\leq n&\iff 3n+1\leq 3n+n\\
&\iff 3n+1\leq 4n\\
&\iff 3n+1+2\leq 4n+2 \\
&\iff 3n+3\leq 4n+2.
\end{align}
And it proved.

As @ArB comment's,

Consider that
$$3n+3\leq 4n+2\iff 4n+2\geq 3n+3\iff 4n+2-3n-3\geq 0\iff n-1\geq 0\iff n\geq 1.$$
Since $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 1$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality must be $3n+3\leq 4n+2\  \forall  n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
 It is actually a simple one, observe,
 you want to prove $3n+3\leq 4n+2\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ that is to prove $0\leq n-1\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ which is already true.

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove $$3n+3 \le 4n+2$$ or $$1 \le n$$ Now since $n$ is a natural number, $$n \in {1,2,3....}$$ Now we can easily see that $1$ is either equal to or less than $n$. Now we proved $$1 \le n$$ so by this we can prove the original inequality